# How to get size of file geodatabase feature class on disk?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, file-geodatabase, arccatalog

Is there a simple way to determine the amount of hard drive space a feature class takes up?

I feel like I'm missing something simple, but I don't recall a method that does so.

You would think that right-clicking a dataset in ArcCatalog would do it for you.

The best I've ever been able to do was get the size of the entire gdb by looking in Windows Explorer.

If there isn't a way to do this in the ArcCatalog UI, I'd still be interested in a method to do so in code.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you're looking for an ArcObjects way to get it, then [How to programmatically determine the size of a feature class in a file geodatabase?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24242/how-to-programmatically-determine-the-size-of-a-feature-class-in-a-file-geodatab) will provide that -- otherwise, you can enable the **Size** column in the **Customize** menu -> **ArcCatalog Options** -> **Contents** tab:

[image: Enabling size column in ArcCatalog Options -> Contents tab]
[image: Size column enabled reveals feature class is 50.69 MB]

This works on file geodatabases but not on SDE geodatabases (in that case you could use some DBMS-specific queries to determine it though). It does **not** work on personal geodatabases.

Comment: It's also worth noting that, for whatever reason, this option doesn't display raster sizes.