# Calculating space feature class will use in ArcSDE?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, file-geodatabase, oracle-dbms, arcgis-9.2

Is it possible to get a good estimate on how much space a feature class will take once loaded into ArcSDE from how big they are in a FGDB? I have some feature classes in a FGDB, where some are a few GB's.

I'm using Oracle/ ArcSDE 9.2

Answer (score 1):

you can get the same information [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/23920/3071) - How to get the size of a file geodatabase feature class on disk?

```
enable the Size column in the Customize menu -> ArcCatalog Options -> Contents tab
```

i hope it helps you...

Comment: On disk is fine, as that is what I'm doing at the moment, I want to find out whether from the file sizes in the FGDB I can estimate the size before I load it into ArcSDE.

Comment: Estimate, sure. It will generally be larger on SDE because there are more metadata tables and different storage types may be less efficient space wise. Why not do a test? Put up a small feature class and ask your DBAs to figure out its size (hopefully they will know how, it's not a simple matter). Compare the two and extrapolate from the difference for your real feature classes.

Answer (score 1):

for ArcSDE run the script below in MSSQL Manager Studio. Then save it as csv, open in excel and sort / sum ...

```
SELECT 
    t.NAME AS TableName,
    p.rows AS RowCounts,
    SUM(a.total_pages) * 8 AS TotalSpaceKB, 
    SUM(a.used_pages) * 8 AS UsedSpaceKB, 
    (SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8 AS UnusedSpaceKB
FROM 
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN      
    sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
WHERE 
    t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%' 
    AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND i.OBJECT_ID > 255 
GROUP BY 
    t.Name, p.Rows
ORDER BY 
    t.Name
```